# Why is there a minus sign on the right hand side, when the ket flips?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

How is the right hand side obtained from the left hand side in this equation?

$$ \int \mathrm{d}x' | x' + \Delta x' \rangle \langle x' | \alpha \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x' | x' \rangle \langle x' - \Delta x' | \alpha \rangle$$

Where does the minus sign come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a change of variables

\begin{eqnarray}
\int{\rm d}x' | x' + \Delta x' \rangle \langle x'| \alpha \rangle &\stackrel{y = x' + \Delta x'}{=}& \int{\rm d}y | y \rangle \langle y - \Delta x'| \alpha \rangle \\
&\stackrel{y\to x'}=& \int{\rm d}x' | x' \rangle \langle x' - \Delta x'| \alpha \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If y = x', and the third expression is equivalent to the second expression, and in the second expression y = x' + Delta x', then combining the two equations for y gives x' = x' + Delta x', which implies that Delta x' is 0. Why is this statement incorrect?

Comment: He's not saying $y=x'$, exactly. In the second expression, $y$ is integrated over, and the expression is true no matter what you call $y$. For example he could have said $y\rightarrow z$, or $y \rightarrow $ anything really. If a variable is integrated over, it doesn't matter what you call the variable.

Comment: @Math12345 The second change of variables reflects the fact that you can call an integration variable as you wish

Comment: So y = x' + \Delta x' and y = x' are not simultaneously true? Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: For example, for the last expression, by the argument of being able to replace a variable with anything even if the variable has already been used, I could replace y in the second expression with \Delta x'. But doing so would give 0, which probably isn't correct.

Comment: $y\to x'$ means you _rename_ $y$ to $x'$, which creates a new variable called $x'$, different from the $x'$ that appears in the original equation. There are actually two $x'$s, an "original" one and a "new" one. $y = x'_{\text{original}} + \Delta x'$ but $y = x'_{\text{new}}$. (It certainly would be better if the answer made it more clear that this is happening; that being said, renaming a variable like this is a fairly common thing to do.)